# nested routes with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nested-routes

I am very new in react. I am working with typescript-react(.tsx). I am struggling in nested routes. if url is like file:///D:/original/22-02-2017/app.html#/job-home
then the "horMenu" component will loads, in that only one horizontal menu is available. And inside the indexroute of that the "Jobpage" component will loads. It is working fine. But in horizontal menu when i click on Approvals the "Approvals" component should load, and inside that the another component should load called "ThirdMenu". And inside "ThirdMenu" component the "ThirdMenuData" component should load. In short when i click on "Approvals" three component should load at same time.

My routing code is as follows:

```html
<Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="job-home" component={horMenu} >
          <IndexRoute component={JobPage} />
          <Route path="/approvals" component={Approvals}>
            <Route path="/" component={ThirdMenu}>
                <IndexRoute component={ThirdMenuData} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
```

And my components code as follows:

**Approvals**

```js
export var Approvals = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function()
    {    
       return(
        {
            "secondmenudata":[
                            {"name":"STEPS","id":1,"url":"steps"},
                            {"name":"RFI","id":2,"url":"rfi"},
                            {"name":"NCR","id":3,"url":"ncr"},
                            {"name":"SIGN-OFFS","id":4,"url":"sign-offs"}
                        ]
        });
    },
 render: function() {
  return (
   <div>
    <ul className="nav nav-pills tab-2" role="tablist">
       {
      this.state.secondmenudata.map(function(name:any) 
      {
       return <li  key={name.id}><Link to={"/"+name.url} >{name.name}</Link></li>
      })
     }  
    </ul>
        <div className="scrolling-tabs-container3" >
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
});
```

**ThirdMenu**

```js
export var ThirdMenu = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function()
    {
      return{
        "thirdmenudata":[
                            {"name":"Unit 1","id":1,"url":"unit1"},
                            {"name":"Unit 2","id":2,"url":"Unit2"},
                            {"name":"Unit 3","id":3,"url":"Unit3"},
                            {"name":"Unit 4","id":4,"url":"Unit4"},
                            {"name":"Unit 5","id":5,"url":"Unit5"},
                            {"name":"Unit 6","id":6,"url":"Unit6"},
                            {"name":"Unit 7","id":7,"url":"Unit7"},
                            {"name":"Unit 8","id":8,"url":"Unit8"}
                        ]
      };
    },
    render:function()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <div >
                  <ul className="nav nav-pills tab-3" role="tablist">
                      {
                          this.state.thirdmenudata.map(function(name:any) 
                          {
                                return <li  key={name.id}><Link  role="pill" data-toggle="pill" to={"/"+name.url} >{name.name}</Link></li>
                          })
                      }  
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div>{this.props.childern}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

**ThirdMenuData**

```js
export var ThirdMenu = React.createClass({
   
    render:function()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>this is approval Data</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Plz help what is wrong with my code

**UPDATED**

but when i put following route

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="job-home" component={horMenu} >
             <IndexRoute component={JobPage} />
             <Route path="/approvals" component={Approvals}>
               <Route  component={ThirdMenu}>
                  <IndexRoute component={ThirdMenuData} />
             </Route>
       </Route>
      </Route>

    </Router>
```

then only last component "ThirdMenuData" not displayed

My structure should look like this
[image]

Comment: no any errors displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old version of react router. Now we can use easy and very dynamic version of [React router v4 or React Router Dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy).

In this, child routes used inside the appropriate component where we want to display the route's component.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your routes. You cannot have `/` route under `/approvals`, because this is `<IndexRoute />` in it's essence.

See below for modified routes

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="job-home" component={horMenu} >
      <IndexRoute component={JobPage} />
      <Route component={Approvals}>
        <Route path="approvals" component={ThirdMenu}>
          <IndexRoute component={ThirdMenuData} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

With the given nested configuration your menu should show up when you got to `domain.com/job-home/approvals`

#### Edit

Appending additional routes

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="job-home" component={horMenu} >
      <IndexRoute component={JobPage} />
      <Route path="approvals" component={Approvals}>
        <Route path="third-menu" component={ThirdMenu}>
          <IndexRoute component={ThirdMenuData} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: i cant do that because i have too many routes with similar components with ThirdMenu..

Comment: @HardikChaudhary what do you mean? Can you give an example that you are using?

Comment: see an image in question

Comment: @HardikChaudhary I have updated my answer. You were missing a closing `</Route>` tag when using `ThirdMenu` component. The above structure works.

Comment: @HardikChaudhary do you get any errors? What part is not shown? I need more info to debug this.

Comment: @HardikChaudhary check the updated post. With the given nested configuration your menu should show up when you got to `domain.com/job-home/approvals`

Comment: in the question an image where the ThirdMenuData is written that is the area where data of this component should print. I want three components to be loaded when i have  domain.com/approvals this url

Comment: @HardikChaudhary `<IndexRoute />` can be used only for 1 level deep components. Check my update.

Comment: I know that but what if we have this kind of situations??

Comment: @HardikChaudhary then you can 1) import the components inside other components; 2) append additional route, e.g. `domain.com/job-home/approvals/thirdMenu`; 3) use tabs with components state.

Comment: how can i append additional routes?

Comment: it is producing an error:     Warning: [react-router] Location "/approvals" did not match any routes

Comment: @HardikChaudhary because you must change your link to `.../approvals/third-menu` since `/approvals` does not exist.

Comment: @HardikChaudhary happy to help! `domain.com/job-home/approvals/third-menu` is a valid route using the definition provided in the edit. Please check the code for typos.